# I need to find least count by iterating child array and seperate as multiple arrays based on parent array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
myData = [
  {
    id: 'N5604-E',
    areas: [
      {
        test_per_week: 154,
        test_per_day: 22,
      },
      {
        test_per_week: 154,
        test_per_day: 52,
      },
      {
        test_per_week: 154,
        test_per_day: 32,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'RSP4-E',
    areas: [
      {
        test_per_week: 154,
        test_per_day: 12,
      },
      {
        test_per_week: 154,
        test_per_day: 29,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to get minimum `test_per_week` in each area and need to store values in an array based on IDs

I have tried iterating using for loop and for each loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
  this.chartProducts.push(this.data[i].id);
  this.capacity[i].areas.forEach((element) => {
    this.myData.push(element.test_per_day);
  });
}
```

I stuck on how to calculate the min count of `test_per_day` for all areas in one ID.

Comment: what do you mean by minimum test per week ? samllest  value in the array of objects?

Comment: Yes,need to form an array with smallest value within area object array for each ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) as follows:

```
const result = myData.map(o => ({
  id: o.id,
  min_per_day: Math.min(...o.areas.map(a => a.test_per_day))
}));
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const myData = [{
    "id": "N5604-E",
    "areas": [
      { "test_per_week": 154, "test_per_day": 22 },
      { "test_per_week": 154, "test_per_day": 52 },
      { "test_per_week": 154, "test_per_day": 32 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "RSP4-E",
    "areas": [
      { "test_per_week": 154, "test_per_day": 12 },
      { "test_per_week": 154, "test_per_day": 29 }
    ]
  }
];

const result = myData.map(o => ({
  id: o.id,
  min_per_day: Math.min(...o.areas.map(a => a.test_per_day))
}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

We used a `map` method for iterating and return a new `array` and reduce for comparing the values between together and finally using the `min` mathematical method to get the minimum number.

```
const result = myData.map((item) => {
  const test_per_day = item.areas.reduce(
    (max, val) => Math.min(max, val.test_per_day),
    item.areas[0].test_per_day
  );

  return { id: item.id, test_per_day };
});
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "N5604-E",
    "test_per_day": 22
  },
  {
    "id": "RSP4-E",
    "test_per_day": 12
  }
]
```